# @OneToOne\OneToMany Can't find inverse attribute HIbernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

[@OneToMany](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJaol.jpg)
I have this error "Can't find inverse attribute" while going through the Spring course. In the course there is no issue with this code but I have. Maybe some one could help?

Instructor.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "instructor")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Instructor {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "instructor_detail_id")
    private InstructorDetail instructorDetail;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "instructor")
    private List<Course> courses;

    public Instructor(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Instructor{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", instructorDetail=" + instructorDetail +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Course.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "course")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Course {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "instructor_id")
    private Instructor instructor;

    public Course(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Course{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", title='" + title + '\'' +
                ", instructor=" + instructor +
                '}';
    }
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- JDBC Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hb-03-one-to-many?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC</property>
        <property name="connection.username"></property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool settings ... using built-in test pool -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- Select our SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Echo the SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>

        <!-- Set the current session context -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
 
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

I found that it could be fixed by "inverse" attribute in some POJO mapping xml classes. But I don't use them and in lesson there is no using of this classes too.

Comment: Is there actually an error when you run the code or is it just an IDE thing?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer actually you are right. It is only IDE thing. The code works fine. Hmm... but still anoying and want to resolve this error)

Comment: You can probably turn it off in the IDE setting somewhere. Its probably just a warning

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

`Inverse` attribute is normally used to let hibernate know which side is the relationship owner. In hibernate, only the 'relationship owner' should maintain the relation, means updating the foreign key column in case of any update. But in your case it is `one-to-many`  `bi directional` in which case the inverse is by default true for the many side. You can try manually mentioning `inverse=true` in the courses side though it is not actually necessary.

Comment: But where exactly I should add this "inverse" attribute? I don't use any othe .xml configuration for classes